# Fluid Separation

Tags: water, phase

I've been trying to find a way to prevent cornstarch and water from separating. If I'm right, emulsifiers are used to prevent fluid seperation with oils, but will an emulsifier fix my problem too? If so, will it break the non-Newtonian properties of the solution?